# Accessing the context of a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, spinner

I work on an android app (Kotlin) and I'm trying to make a fragment which contains a spinner - the list of languages. Though I struggle with passing a "context" to an ArrayAdapter.

I tried using "this" and "context". But neither of those worked. Smart casting with "let" doesn't solve the issue and adding "ifs" for null checking doesn't solve the issue either.

How can I access "context" of a fragment? Here I have the code in which I check if the fragment has been added to an activity but the compiler still sees it as "context?" not as "context".

```
class QuickTranslation : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentQuickTranslationBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentQuickTranslationBinding>(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_quick_translation, container, false
        )

        if (isAdded) { // HERE I check if contex is null
            val originalLangSpinner = binding.originalLangSpinner

            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                context, // ERROR Type missmatch. Required: Context, Found: Context?
                R.array.supported_languages,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
            ).also { adapter ->
                // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                originalLangSpinner.adapter = adapter
            }
        }
        return binding.root
    }

}
```

Comment: try `requireContext()` instead of `context`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `requireContext()` or `getActivity()` in Fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

Use `activity!!` and get the context out of it.